# SQL Database using JDBC + parameterize SQL Query + Databricks

Tags: python, sql, scala, jdbc, databricks

In Databricks am reading SQL table as

```
val TransformationRules = spark.read.jdbc(jdbcUrl, "ADF.TransformationRules", connectionProperties)
.select("RuleCode","SourceSystem","PrimaryTable", "PrimaryColumn", "SecondaryColumn", "NewColumnName","CurrentFlag")
.where("SourceSystem = 'QWDS' AND RuleCode = 'STD00003' ")
```

How can I parameterize `SourceSystem` and `RuleCode` in `Where` clause

Was referring to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/sql-databases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you import the spark implicits, you can create references to columns with the dollar `$` interpolator. Also, you can use the API with columns to make the logic, it will be something like this.

```
val sourceSystem = "QWDS"
val ruleCode = "STD00003"

import spark.implicits._
val TransformationRules = spark.read.jdbc(jdbcUrl, "ADF.TransformationRules", connectionProperties)
.select("RuleCode","SourceSystem","PrimaryTable", "PrimaryColumn", "SecondaryColumn", "NewColumnName","CurrentFlag")
.where($"SourceSystem" === sourceSystem && $"RuleCode" === ruleCode)

val ssColumn: Column = $"SourceSystem"
```

As you can see, the dollar will provide a Column object, with logic like cooperation, casting renaming etc. In combination with the functions in `org.apache.spark.sql.function` will allow you to implement almost all you need.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i unterstand your question correctly, you want to insert values into the where clause string? Maybe then the underneath solutions could work for you:

```
val TransformationRules = spark.read.jdbc(jdbcUrl, "ADF.TransformationRules", connectionProperties)
.select("RuleCode","SourceSystem","PrimaryTable", "PrimaryColumn", "SecondaryColumn", "NewColumnName","CurrentFlag")
.where("SourceSystem = '{}' AND RuleCode = '{}' ".format(sourceSystem, ruleCode))
```